# How can I get MVC 4 on Visual Web Developer 2010?

Tags: web, express

Im trying to add MVC 4 to WD2010 Express but im not finding any link or tools to do so, can someone help me out?

Comment: The ASP.NET MVC project templates aren't appearing under File > New Project?

Comment: I only have MVC 2, not 4..

Comment: @DezmenCeoSykes Are you using SP1?

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2010, MVC 4 must be downloaded and installed manually. You can find it here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4.

Comment: this is only for VS not VWB

Comment: Did you try it? Works for me. You have to go through New Project instead of New Website, but the project templates and all are definitely there. Try upgrading to SP1 before installing if you're not using it already.